# Recreating a imagemagick command with PIL

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I have a command:

`composite -colorspace gray -quality 99 -compose plus t-1.jpg x-1.jpg 2.jpg`

I would like to produce the same effect in python. I tried this:

```
from PIL import Image
imga = Image.open('t-1.jpg')
imgb = Image.open('x-1.jpg')
ab = PIL.Image.blend( imga, imgb, 0.5)
ab.save("test.jpg")
```

They test.jpg and 2.jpg do not looking anything alike. This would mean that  `-compose plus` does not equal to `blend( imga, imgb, 0.5)`. Docs for the compose plus command is [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#plus).  What is a comparable operation for `-compose plus` in imagemagick?

Answer (score 0):

Found it right after I asked the question.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
imga = Image.open('t-1.jpg')
imgb = Image.open('x-1.jpg')
ab = ImageChops.add(imga, imgb,1,0)
ab.save("test.jpg")
```